# matplotlib plot progress of variable written into file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to find a way to run a python script that plot the value contained in a file, but the plot should persist to check and update the plot because the file is dynamically updating from another programs .. 
there is a solution about ?

Comment: A `while True:` infinite loop and a plot with hold. hold is deprecated, so now that you have the base idea, look into the matplotlib documentation and come up with a proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what [Mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8324480/mathieu) suggested, I would also recommend having a running loop, however,  `while True` loops are costly for your system. I would suggest a routine that runs once an update, just after your file updates.

You can use `time.sleep()` (import Time to use it) until your update occures thus saving redundant counters etc'.

It should look something like this:

```
plt.figure()  # Opens a figure you can plot in. Redundant, but more understandable
while True:  # I suggest replacing with a halting condition/input
    #update your data object, denoted obj, from your files. 
    hold(true)
    plot('xlabel', 'ylabel', data=obj)
    time.sleep(10) # Assumes Time is imported, this will wait for 10 seconds before looping.
```

That being said, if you're planning on redrawing a line plot, after a few iterations, things will get unclear in one graph. 
In that case, I would suggest two solutions which come to mind, though I'm sure there are more:

1) Divide into plots/subplots for every constant amount of iterations. I would say more than 5 graphs in one figure is already hard to follow thus, keep it in 5's or less.

2) Plot the difference between every iteration. This is much cleaner and you can keep track of two types of differences. Accumulated and per iteration. I think this is quite useful.

If what you're updating is not a line graph, but rather a {x,y} graph (data points). Ignore the two solutions above and plot away.

It all depends on what sort of plot you're planning to make and what data you seek to extract from the plots.

Comment: A nit: it's `time.sleep(10)` and not `Time.sleep(10)` =)